# PHP next functions but with a string using delimiters

Tags: php, string

I have a string like

```
$str = 'moba/cool/light/from/miami/cyborg';
```

What I want to select is, from the begining to the string to a specifc sub-string.
Like If I want to output this:

`moba/cool/light/from`
I have this code:

```
$pos = strpos($str, 'from');
$strPretty = substr($str, 0, next($pos));
```

**Note the next on the `$strPretty` I just want to take the next delimiter**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `next()` does not work in that situation, but a simple change should do it for you. as the `strpos()` gives you the byte number where the search string starts, you just need to add the length of the search string to the 3rd param of the `substr()`

```
$str = 'moba/cool/light/from/miami/cyborg';
$search = 'from';

$pos = strpos($str, $search);
$strPretty = substr($str, 0, $pos + strlen($search));
echo $strPretty;
```

RESULT

```
moba/cool/light/from
```